# Cannot update Laravel from 5.8 to 6

Tags: laravel

I can't update Laravel from 5.8.38 to 6

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.24
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.23
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.22
    ...
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.0.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.0.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.0.0
    - zizaco/entrust 5.2.x-dev requires illuminate/cache ~5.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.38], illuminate/cache[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, 5.2.x-dev, 5.3.x-dev, 5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].
    - zizaco/entrust 5.2.x-dev requires illuminate/cache ~5.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.38], illuminate/cache[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, 5.2.x-dev, 5.3.x-dev, 5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[6.x-dev, v5.8.38].
    - don't install illuminate/cache 5.0.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/cache 5.1.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/cache 5.2.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/cache 5.3.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/cache 5.4.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/cache 5.5.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/cache 5.6.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/cache v5.8.4|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/cache v5.8.8|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/cache v5.8.9|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - Installation request for laravel/framework ^6.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[6.x-dev, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.10.0, v6.10.1, v6.11.0, v6.12.0, v6.13.0, v6.13.1, v6.14.0, v6.15.0, v6.15.1, v6.16.0, v6.17.0, v6.17.1, v6.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.10, v6.18.11, v6.18.12, v6.18.13, v6.18.14, v6.18.15, v6.18.16, v6.18.17, v6.18.18, v6.18.19, v6.18.2, v6.18.20, v6.18.21, v6.18.22, v6.18.23, v6.18.24, v6.18.3, v6.18.4, v6.18.5, v6.18.6, v6.18.7, v6.18.8, v6.18.9, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0, v6.9.0].
    - Installation request for zizaco/entrust 5.2.x-dev -> satisfiable by zizaco/entrust[5.2.x-dev].
```

This is my Composer.json

```
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.4",
        "anhskohbo/no-captcha": "^3.2",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "intervention/image": "dev-master",
        "laravel-notification-channels/webpush": "^5.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^6.0",
        "cmgmyr/messenger": "^2.20",
        "laravel/passport": "7.5.1",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "zizaco/entrust": "5.2.x-dev",
        "gghughunishvili/entrust": "^2.0",
        "kylekatarnls/laravel-carbon-2": "^1.0.0",
        "nesbot/carbon": "2.0.0-beta.2 as 1.25.0"
    }
```

The error shows that this "gghughunishvili/entrust": "^2.0"" packages needs cache version 6, but I can't figure how can i update it. Even when i remove that line, i receive error that Laravel 6 needs Cache version 6.

EDIT:

I managed to update it, now i am receiving another error.

```
Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie::__construct() must be of the type string, null given, called in /home/devtreniraj/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php on line 157
```

This is the function and line 157

```
protected function addCookieToResponse(Response $response, Session $session)
    {
        if ($this->sessionIsPersistent($config = $this->manager->getSessionConfig())) {
            $response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie(
                $session->getName(), $session->getId(), $this->getCookieExpirationDate(),
                $config['path'], $config['domain'], $config['secure'] ?? false,
                $config['http_only'] ?? true, false, $config['same_site'] ?? null
            ));
        }
    }
```

Line 157:
$config['http_only'] ?? true, false, $config['same_site'] ?? null

Comment: There is no mention of `gghughunishvili/entrust` in the error message you provided, the error only mentions `zizaco/entrust`, and it seems that this package does not support Laravel 6, so you would have to remove it and find a replacement.

Comment: I removed it to test will it update it without it. But there is an error thats says i need cache ver 6

Comment: @NikolaRanisavljev remove this line "zizaco/entrust": "5.2.x-dev", from composer and then try to update

Comment: @KhalidKhan i managed to update it. Now i am facing with another error.. you can see my updated question after "EDIT"

Comment: @NikolaRanisavljev remove this line  "gghughunishvili/entrust": "^2.0", as well

Comment: @KhalidKhan why? I updated it, its working now and its on Laravel 6. Now i am facing with another problem, with Sessions.. I always receive error 419, but its working on Laravel 5.

Comment: @NikolaRanisavljev are you using csrf token ? use it or else 419 error will come

Comment: Yes, application works on Laravel 5.8, everything was fine, now it won't work.

Comment: @NikolaRanisavljev Did you follow the [upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade#upgrade-6.0) and update your code and config files?

Comment: Yes, i followed..

Comment: @NikolaRanisavljev Just so you know, not all the config file changes are in the upgrade guide, you have to manually go to the github repo and look through each config file.

Comment: @NikolaRanisavljev And it is impossible to help you with the error that you provided, I don't believe that the error is in the Laravel codebase, it has to be somewhere in your code.

Comment: Well maybe, i have now error 419 and i think i am missing something stupid..will check config in their repo. Thanks man!